# A comparison between "escape to", "flee to", "run away to" and "get away to"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, verbs, word-difference

I need to know if all the four verbs work properly withing the following sentence? If yes, then they mean the same thing in everyday speech? And if they have some semantic nuances, how do they differ in meaning and how they can affect the meaning of the same sentence?

> - Endward Snowden escaped to Russia.
>
>   - Endward Snowden fled to Russia.
>   - Endward ran away ran away to Russia.
>   - Endward got away got away to Russia.

To me, they all work and are interchangeable in this sense.

Thank you.

Comment: I assumed you did not intend to leave the word "escaped" in the third and fourth sentences.

Comment: I'm sure you didn't intend the duplication either, in third and fourth.

Comment: "Got away to [location]" pings my ear as peculiar. You can see that the others have differences in whether they're more commonly used with "to" or with "from" in this google ngram: [Link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+away+to%2Cgot+away+from%2Cescaped+to%2Cescaped+from%2Cfled+to%2Cfled+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20away%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20away%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cescaped%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cescaped%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfled%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfled%20from%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a person being chased, as Edward Snowden was, all four are pretty much the same.  "Fled" is very slightly more formal, "Got away" slightless less formal.

But you can also use "fled" and "ran away" even if no one might be chasing you:

- Broken hearted, he fled / ran away to Russia.